# An example of how to use block response in Restkit?

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, restkit

Instead of a clustered:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{            
    if (objectLoader.method == RKRequestMethodGET) {
        if ([objectLoader.resourcePath isEqualToString:@"/blah"]) {
            // ...
        }
    } else if (objectLoader.method == RKRequestMethodPUT) {
        if ([objectLoader.resourcePath hasSuffix:@"/blahblah"]) {
            // ...
        }        
    } else if (objectLoader.method == RKRequestMethodPOST) {
        if ([objectLoader.resourcePath isEqualToString:@"/blahblahblah"]) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'd prefer a `block` approach, especially for simpler requests without any object mapping. Is there any documentation or example of how to use block response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is support for this configuration in the latest (0.10.1) version of RestKit.

There is `- (void)loadObjectsAtResourcePath:(NSString *)resourcePath usingBlock:(RKObjectLoaderBlock)block` selector, however the block is invoked to allow you to configure the `ObjectLoader`.

You may also use `userData` property to distinguish multiple requests, i provided more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387253/restkit-distinguish-multiple-requests-in-didloadresponse/8387649#8387649).

Answer (score 0):

With 0.10.1, you can use blocks for POST, GET etc calls, [check out this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379294/630996)